# How to open a file in R studios (version 4.0.3) from GLODAP?

Tags: r, geospatial, netcdf, rgdal

I'm very new to coding in R and do not know what I am doing. I am trying to map some environmental variables but I cannot open this one file. This is the link to the files I want to open:

https://www.nodc.noaa.gov/archive/arc0107/0162565/2.2/data/0-data/mapped/

This link opens to a page with 2 folders in which I would like the `GLODAPv2_Mapped_Climatology.tar.gz` I do not know if I need to add this into the link when trying to open in R. I do not know what link is needed but this is the download link:

https://www.nodc.noaa.gov/archive/arc0107/0162565/2.2/data/0-data/mapped/GLODAPv2_Mapped_Climatology.tar.gz

I have tried downloading this folder and when I open in R it shows no data for the specific environmental variables in the mapped climatology variables, I think it is because the file is too large, so I saw coding where you use the link to open the folder in R.

So if someone could please help me in telling me how to open this folder into r and how to extract the files I specifically want for my maps, In this file I would like to access these 4 variables:

```
GLODAPv2.OmegaAinsitu
GLODAPv2.OmegaCinsitu
GLODAPv2.talk
GLODAPv2.tco2
```

I have tried everything to try and get the files into R but all the coding I try doesn't work. If someone knows how to get these files into R and produce them into maps I would be very grateful!

Comment: Have you read the [README.txt](https://www.nodc.noaa.gov/archive/arc0107/0162565/1.1/data/0-data/mapped/README.txt) file? It says that the version you link to is outdated due to some errors.

Comment: The files in the tar.gz archive are NetCDF files, see, for instance, this CRAN package [`ncdf4` vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/futureheatwaves/vignettes/starting_from_netcdf.html)  and this [RPubs](https://rpubs.com/boyerag/297592) post on how to read them in R.